# Working with *ngIf within *ngFor to display certain selective element

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a div within my component html which I want to hide on page load and want to show on link click. I have multiple divs within *ngFor loop and I have assigned *ngIf = showReply[commentData.id] to each div so that it stay hidden when component load.

Later when I click on a link I call a function and I will set id to true.

below is HTML snippet:

```
<!-- Reply Link -->
```

This is the link on clicking which I want to show the div

```
        <div class="addReplyContainer" >
          <a  class="addReplyLink"  (click)="showReplyTextArea($event, 'showreply'+commentData.id)">Reply</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Add Reply -->
        <div [attr.commentId] = "commentData.target_id" *ngIf = "'showReply'[commentData.id]"
             class="addReplyContainer replyTextAreaContainer" >
          <textarea (keyup)="keyUpCommentTextarea(reply, commentData.id)" [(ngModel)]="reply" style="width:100%"
                    class="replyText commentText addReplyTextarea form-control"></textarea>
          <button [attr.commentId]="commentData.id" disabled class="btn btn-success addCommentBtn" (click)="addReply(commentData.target_id)">Add</button>
        </div>
```

Below is component

list-comments.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';
import { CommentsDataService} from "../../services/comments/comments-data.service";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {IComment} from "../../comments";
import {ICommentType} from "../../commentType";



declare let jQuery: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-comments',
  templateUrl: './list-comments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-comments.component.css'],
  providers:[CommentsDataService]

})
export class ListCommentsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private commentsDataService:CommentsDataService, private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  commentsData :any; // Comment Data received from service.
  comment:string; // Comment text; declaration.
  reply:string;
  commentObj:any;
  commentArrayObj:any;
  public showreply_commentData;
  getComments;  // Declaration of function.
  saveComment;
  getUser;




  /**
   * This Function is triggered to
   * call save function and append
   * new comment.
   * Append new comment
   *
   */
  addComment()
  {

    this.comment = this.comment.trim();
    let commentObj;
    let comment = this.comment;
    commentObj ={
      "root_id":"1",
      "target_id": "1",
      "object": this.comment,
      "time_stamp":'2 secs ago',
      "profile_image":"/../../assets/images/no-user.png",
      "first_name" : "john",
    };

    //let commentObj = this.commentObj; //Put this.commentObj to push it into this.commentData

    if( typeof this.comment == "undefined" || this.comment === '' || this.comment == null ||  this.comment == '\n' || this.comment.length>500 )
    {

      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      this.commentsData.push( commentObj );
      this.comment = ''; // Empty comment Textarea.
      return comment;

    }

  }

  /**
   *
   * Function triggered when
   * reply link is clicked
   * @param event
   * @param targetId
   */
  showReplyTextArea(event, ngIf);
  showReplyTextArea(event, ngIf)
  {

    ngIf = true
    console.log(ngIf)

  }
```

If showreply[commentData.id] == false/ showreply[commentData.id] == true is right way to toggle ngIf for such ngFor?

Please Assist.

Thanks!

***UPDATE**

I have used solution suggested by **Tony Roczz**

I have used index of ngFor to set ngIf expression true or false.

HTML:

```
  <!-- Reply Link -->
            <div class="addReplyContainer" >
              <a  class="addReplyLink"  (click)="showReplyTextArea($event,i )">Reply</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Add Reply -->
            <div [attr.commentId] = "commentData.target_id" *ngIf = "selectedIndex == i "
                 class="addReplyContainer replyTextAreaContainer" >
              <textarea (keyup)="keyUpCommentTextarea(reply, commentData.id)" [(ngModel)]="reply" style="width:100%"
                        class="replyText commentText addReplyTextarea form-control"></textarea>
              <button [attr.commentId]="commentData.id" disabled class="btn btn-success addCommentBtn" (click)="addReply(commentData.target_id)">Add</button>
            </div>
            <!-- -----Add Reply end------ -->
```

**Component**

```
  showReplyTextArea(event, index)
  {


    this.selectedIndex = index; // Whenever user click on reply link the 
                                //  respective index is set equal to 
                                //  selectedIndex variable


    console.log( this.selectedindex);

  }
```

Thanks @Tony Roczz and @kaddath for Help.

Comment: NOTE: if you set your `id` to `true`, the divs will stay hidden, as `!id` will be `false`

Comment: Ok. Let me recheck quickly and i will update my question.

Comment: if you have a `*ngFor` then along with `id` you can check if the `index` values match.

Comment: @Kaddath I have used showreply string concatenation with commentData.id, to set ngIf true or false.

Comment: @TonyRoczz Can you guide how index value can be used to set ngIf true or false clicking link?

Comment: you edited the question with new way to do it, but gave no feedback, does it work as expected? if not, what is going wrong? any error message? values not as expected? Your question is still vague, i could answer saying "yes, a boolean value in a `*ngIf` that you change is the right way to toggle it"

Comment: In your `component` file have variable like `selectedindex` and when you click a link set `selectedindex` to the index of the clicked link. In `*ngIf` along with the existing condition check if `selectedindex==$index`

Comment: @Kaddath Sorry I did not explain the outputs in detail. In showReply function printed  console.log(ngIf) and it prints strings like showReply567 and showReply444 and I set it to true or false but ngIf does not change. That is element does not show up.

Comment: @TonyRoczz Thanks For explaining this logic. It worked for me.

Comment: Update your question with solution it might help others.